# How to remove number strings from a set?

Tags: python, string, set

If I have a set:

```
{'NYC', 'Ames', 'LA', 'Houston', '500', '1000', '3000',
 'SanFrancisco', '300', '200', 'Detroit', 'Austin'}
```

How can I remove all the numeric strings from the set?

To be clear I want this:

```
{'NYC', 'Ames', 'LA', 'Houston', 'SanFrancisco', 'Detroit', 'Austin'}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To build on Meccano's answer, you can also use a set comprehension to shorten the code using the `.isdigit` str method:

```
old_set = {'NYC', 'Ames', 'LA', 'Houston', '500',  '1000', '3000', 
                  'SanFrancisco', '300', '200', 'Detroit', 'Austin'}

new_set = {elem for elem in old_set if not elem.isdigit()}
print(new_set)
# output:
# {'NYC', 'Ames', 'LA', 'Houston', 'SanFrancisco', 'Detroit', 'Austin'}
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use the string.isdigit() to check whether a string is a number or not:

```
new_set = set()
for elem in old_set:
    if not elem.isdigit():
        new_set.add(elem)
```

Answer (score 1):

do this:

```
l = {'NYC', 'Ames', 'LA', 'Houston', '500', '1000', '3000',
 'SanFrancisco', '300', '200', 'Detroit', 'Austin34'}
l = re.sub("^\d+\s|\s\d+\s|\s\d+$", " ", l)
```

this also removes numbers inside the words

> {'NYC', 'Ames', 'LA', 'Houston',
>         'SanFrancisco', 'Detroit', 'Austin'}

Answer (score 1):

Filter out the digits and create a new set:

```
set_new = set(filter(lambda e: not e.isdigit(), set_old))
```